# Symfony 1.4 Web Debug disappears on any route except "home"

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I've a problem that the web debug bar of Symfony 1.4 only shows if I'm in:

- http://example.com/web/frontend_dev.php
- http://example.com/web/backend_dev.php

But the web debug bar disappears as I soon as I change to :

- http://example.com/web/frontend_dev.php**/**
- http://example.com/web/backend_dev.php**/**

Or any URL for that matter:

- http://example.com/web/frontend_dev.php**/ABC**
- http://example.com/web/backend_dev.php**/ABC**

I've the following config.yml on both frontend & backend:

```yml
# You can find more information about this file on the symfony website:
# http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/04-Settings

prod:
  .settings:
    no_script_name:         false
    logging_enabled:        false

dev:
  .settings:
    error_reporting:        <?php echo (E_ALL | E_STRICT)."\n" ?>
    web_debug:              true
    cache:                  false
    no_script_name:         false
    etag:                   false

test:
  .settings:
    error_reporting:        <?php echo ((E_ALL | E_STRICT) ^ E_NOTICE)."\n" ?>
    cache:                  false
    web_debug:              false
    no_script_name:         false
    etag:                   false

all:
  .settings:
    # Form security secret (CSRF protection)
    #csrf_secret:            00455481226525837a73572945021b6f87587c12
    csrf_secret:            false

    # Output escaping settings
    escaping_strategy:      true
    escaping_method:        ESC_SPECIALCHARS

    # Enable the database manager
    use_database:           true


    enabled_modules: [..., sfGuardAuth,  bhLDAPAuth, sfGuardUser, sfGuardPermission]

    login_module:           bhLDAPAuth
    login_action:           signin

    secure_module:          default
    secure_action:          secure

    error404_module:        default
    error404_action:        error404
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.

Make sure all your other views uses a "complete" layout... this is a well formed HTML structure... with  `<html>` tag, `<head>` tag, `<body>` tag...

It solved my problem.

Comment: Thank you, I checked it out with a very simple layout but even the HTML code for the toolbar is not generated when looking at the HTML output.

Comment: Is not generated because a malformed HTML structure... fix your HTML structure, including valid `<html>`,  `<head>` and `<body>`tags... and web debug bar will reappear.